# Триггер для суммирования значения в поле sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, ssms

Имеются таблицы: Товар и Реализация. [image: ВОт диаграмма]
Хочу сделать триггер на изменение значения в поле Количество в табл. Реализация. После изменения триггер должен умножать "ЦенаЗакупки" на значение в "Количество" таблицы Реализация и вставлять полученное значение в "СуммаПродаж".
Я пока додумался до такого варианта: 
create trigger planSALE
after update on Количество
for each row
begin
    update Реализация_ set
        СуммаПродаж = 
            Количество*ЦенаЗакупки;
end;
[image: Вот только sql сразу ругается на after]

Comment: [CREATE TRIGGER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Переопределённые данные. В большинстве случаев (включая данный) - bad practice.